# Facebook SDK. File required is not in the folder

Tags: facebook

This is my first facebook app I am trying to create. I started reading about it, I downloaded the SDK, looked for examples and in every code I found they start with importing a `facebook.php` file that is missing from the SDK folder I downloaded from facebook - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0. Even on github https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk the shown code starts with `require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';`. But once again, this file doesn't exists. How do I use the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong version on github, this is v4: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4

It works completely different, as you can see in the example code. You don´t include a "facebook.php" anymore, you either use Composer or you load the `autoloader.php` in the src folder of the SDK.

Here´s a basic tutorial for the new PHP SDK: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-4-0-tutorial/